# Page not found grappelli-django install

Tags: python, django, django-grappelli

I'm trying to install djanjo-grappeli package.

My setting :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'grappelli',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    #'south',
    'app_salon',
    'app_agenda',
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',

)
```

My urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')), # grappelli URLS
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

But it returns :

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: localhost:8000/grappelli
Using the URLconf defined in salon.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^grappelli/
^admin/
The current URL, grappelli, didn't match any of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `INSTALLED_APPS` like so:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'grappelli',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    #'south',
    'app_salon',
    'app_agenda',
)
```

And make sure you have the following settings:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    ...
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
)
```

Then collect media files:

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic
```

Source: https://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html

Comment: in INSTALLED_APPS "grappelli" is the firts. thank you